# Lightning:dualListbox Issue

Tags: aura, lightning-duallistbox

I'm trying to populate list of options for lightning:dualListbox in my aura component but facing an issue.

I wanted to display the option with combination of two custom fields like `Acc Number + '-' + Acc Name`.

JS Helper:

```
var items = [];
for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
 items.push({label:result[i].field1 + ' - ' + result[i].field2, value:result[i].accountId});
}
component.set("v.options",items);
```

Cmp:

```
<lightning:dualListbox name="Accounts" label="select combination" sourceLabel="Available" selectedLabel="Selected" options="{!v.options}"/>
```

Multipicklist populates as expected, but when I click to select a value, it highlights all picklist options and when I move it to right for selection, only 1 random label is pushed and all others vanish from available box on left. I can't add screenshot here due to restrictions but its weird.

I tried returning wrapper with label and value from apex to eliminate JavaScript helper(thought this might have something to do this JS), but same behavior.

If I make "`value`" and "`label`" same (remove `accountid` from `value` and making `label` and `value` as combination), it works.

But my case is to have value as accId and label as combination so that I can add list of id's for selection and pass to apex for processing.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `accountid` value is different for each option, cause I could reproduce the exact same behavior you describe, and it happens when all options share the same value:

[image]

Hope it helps!